# Torsion filtration of coherent sheaves: Looking for a simple example.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let X be a scheme and let E be a coherent sheaf on X.

A *torsion filtration* (according to Huybrecht's "Geometry of Moduli of Sheaves") for $E$ is the unique filtration $0 \subset T_0(E) \subset T_1(E) \subset \dots \subset T_d(E)=E$, where $d=\dim(E)$ and $T_i(E)$ are the maximal subsheaves of $E$ of dimension $ \le i$.

Unfortunately, no simple example of a torsion filtration is given and I am failing to come up with one on my own.

Are there any good, instructive examples of a torsion filtration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the affine case (so $E$ is just a module over some ring $A$), $T_i(E)$ is just the submodule of $E$ consisting of elements $x\in E$ such that $A/\operatorname{Ann}(x)$ has dimension $\leq i$.  So for a really simple example, you could take $A=k[x,y]$ and $E=A/(x,y)\oplus A/(x)\oplus A$.  Then $T_0(E)$ would be just $A/(x,y)$, $T_1(E)$ would be $A/(x,y)\oplus A/(x)$, and $T_2(E)$ would be all of $E$.

For another example, if $A$ is a domain of dimension $n$, then $T_{n-1}(E)$ is just the submodule of elements of $E$ whose annihilator is nontrivial, i.e. it is the entire torsion submodule of $E$.  For smaller values of $i$, $T_i(E)$ consists of elements that are "more strongly" torsion, such that their annihilator is large enough that when you mod it out you reduce the dimension down to $i$ (or lower).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting example;

For a surface $S$ with curve $C \subset S$ of high genus, we should have a nontrivial extension $0 \to O_C \to L \to O_S$.

Here is a construction. Pick $p \in C$ and take the kernel $K \to O_C(p) \oplus O_S \to O_p$. The kernel is clearly such an extension, and since $h^0(O_C(p)) = 1$ (for $C$ that is not $P^1$!) the extension is nontrivial.